# Using searchCriteria with condition_type operators "from" and "to" in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, search-criteria

I'm trying to use the Get Orders API with searchCriteria to filter Orders with `base_subtotal` range between two values. But I have only been able to use the `lt` and `gt`. I'm unable to use both in the same query.

I can see the [Magento documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html) mentioning that I can do that using the `from` and `to` operators. However, I can't figure out how to get it to work or what is its syntax.

The current request I'm using to get the Orders with `base_subtotal` less than `50`:

```
http://{magento_host}/magento/rest/default/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=base_subtotal&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=50&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=lt
```

What **I'm trying to do is getting the orders where `base_subtotal` < `50` AND `base_subtotal` > `20`.**

Any idea how to do this using `searchCriteria`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it, you can to modify your request in two different ways in my opinion:

### Using less than and greather than

```
http://{magento_host}/magento/rest/default/V1/orders?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=base_subtotal&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=50&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=lt&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=base_subtotal&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=20&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=gt
```

### Using from and to

I'm not entirely sure from/to can be used for normal value range or if it can only be used with dates. Anyway here's how it would be done with from/to

```
http://{magento_host}/magento/rest/default/V1/orders?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=base_subtotal&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=20&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=base_subtotal&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=50&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=to
```